# JS / Javascript Using .push or .unshift is to Track the history of a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working on a book reader.  I have a variable currentPostition that as its name implies, always knows where in the book the user is.  I'm trying to create a history of the users location so I can add a back button like a web browser.  So in the setup I have:

```
currentPostition;  //this is a json object with book,chapter,page stored in it.
history = [];          //array of json objects
```

Then later when the user navigates (there are a few different types of navigation):

```
history.push(currentPostition);  //save in history before updating currpos

//put new values in currentPosition
currentPostition.book = foo;
currentPostition.chapter = foo;
currentPostition.page = foo;
```

So far so good right? Well the problem is such.  My history array grows in length as one would expect.  BUT, every entry in the history array will be the same as the last object placed in the array.  IE:

```
for (x=0;v<history.lenght;x++){
   document.write(history[x].book+","+history[x].chapter+","+history[x].page+"<br />");
}
```

will result in an output of something like

> 3rdBookPosition,3rdChapterPosition,3rdPagePosition
>   3rdBookPosition,3rdChapterPosition,3rdPagePosition
>   3rdBookPosition,3rdChapterPosition,3rdPagePosition

So, I'm stumped cause I expect an output like:

> 1stBookPosition,1stChapterPosition,1stPagePosition
>   2ndBookPosition,2ndChapterPosition,2ndPagePosition
>   3rdBookPosition,3rdChapterPosition,3rdPagePosition

What am I doing wrong?  FYI, I've tried [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and [`history[history.length]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.history) as well and the net the same results.

Thanks in advance,
Jev

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you push the **same instance** of your currentPosition object in your history array.
Doing so you end up with **multiple pointer to the same currentPosition instance**.

To avoid this problem you need to use a **new** currentPosition instance either by using the keyword new if you have a constructor function or by simply copying the object into another like doing `$.extend({},currentPosition)` with jQuery.

Hope this help.

Edit:
You can create your own extends function, something like that:

```
function extends(destObject,srcObject){
  for(var i in srcObject){
    destObject[i] = srcObject[i];
  }
}
```

This is a really simple version you can find slightly more complex version that will clone your object recursively but I imagine i can be sufficient for your question so it would be:

```
var oldPos = extends({},currentPosition);
history.push(oldPos);
```

Comment: I don't have access to jquery.  How else can I copy the object into another without jquery?

Comment: you can declare your own extends function, see edit of the previous response i made

Answer (score 0):

Mostly all in JS is passed by reference. So, you add to array only reference of currentPostition. You need to assign new empty object before using currentPostition another time:

```
currentPostition = {};
```